Compute the residues at the singularities of $f(z) = \frac{\cos z}{z^2(z- \pi )^3}$
Compute the residues at the singularities of   $$f(z) = \frac{\cos z}{z^2(z- \pi )^3}$$

There are two poles: $z=0$ is of order 2 and $z= \pi$ is of order 3. We note that for poles $a$ of order $n$, we have
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=a} f(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \left[(z-a)^n f(z)\right]$$
Using this tool, we have
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
    \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) &= \frac{1}{(2-1)!} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{dz} \left[ \frac{\cos z}{z^2(z- \pi)^3} \right] \\
    &= \lim_{z \to 0} - \frac{(z^2- \pi z)\sin z + (5z - 2\pi) \cos z}{z^3(z-\pi)^4}
    \end{split}
\end{align}
I run into troubles here as I still cannot evaluate the above expression at $z=0$. We could use the Residue Theorem, i.e.
$$\int_C f(z) \hspace{0.2cm} dz = 2 \pi i \sum_{a_k} \mathrm{Res}_{z=a_k} f(z)$$
Maybe we could set $f(z) = \cos z / z^2$ and let $C$ be the curve $|z|=1$. Then $C$ contains $z=0$ but not $z= \pi$. Now, by Cauchy's Integral formula,
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z - \pi)^3} \, dz &= \frac{f''(\pi)}{2!} \hspace{1cm} (\star)
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Now, we note that
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
     & f''(z) = \frac{4z \sin z + (6-z^2) \cos z}{z^4} \\
     \implies & f''(\pi) = \frac{4\pi \sin \pi + (6-\pi^2) \cos \pi}{\pi^4} \\
    \end{split}
\end{align}
Moving the $2 \pi i$ of $(\star)$ to the RHS and simplifying, we get
\begin{equation}
    \int_C \frac{\cos z}{z^2(z- \pi)^3} \hspace{0.2cm} dz = i \frac{4\pi \sin \pi + (6-\pi^2) \cos \pi}{\pi^3}
\end{equation}
EDIT: I am now realizing that I have chosen $C$ in such a way so that $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z=0$ which is contained in $C$. What shall I do instead?

Here is a list of formulas for residue calculations:
https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/an-overview-of-complex-differentiation-and-integration/#Properties-of-Residues
The article and the list are a good opportunity to recap the subject and look-up the formulas.
